# Unreal 4: How to save generated UProceduralMeshComponent to level file in editor and load it at runtime?

Tags: 3d-meshes, unreal, serialization, map-editor

I have UProceduralMeshComponent that I generate in editor from data entered by level designer. Now I need to save it to level file in editor to load it in runtime without generating new mesh again.

Is it possible to do in Unreal Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple. I just need to add a UPROPERTY() keyword to my UProceduralMeshComponent field and call generation function only in editor. The generated mesh will be loaded from level file after you save level.